# Из-за чего блоки с информацией не выстраиваются в 2 колонки

Tags: css, html5, flexbox, blocks

Подскажите пожалуйста, где ошибка в коде? Почему-то блок занимает всю ширину страницы вместо указанной.

```css
.wrapper{
 max-width: 1250px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0px 40px;
}

.blog-list{
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.blog-list_item{
 width: 555px;
 margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.blog-list_img{
 position: relative;
 height: 300px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.blog-list_img img{
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
 min-height: 300px;
}

.blog-list_header{
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 display: flex;
 align-items: flex-end;
}
.blog-list_title{
 background: #fff;
 padding: 25px 20px 10px;
}

.blog-list_icon{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 width: 44px;
 height: 44px;
 background-color: #f39c12;
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #fff;
}

.blog-list_footer{
 display: flex;
 padding-top: 20px;
}

.blog-list_date{
 text-align: right;
 color: #808080;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 24px;
}

.blog-list_date span{
 display: block;
 white-space: nowrap;
}

.blog-list_info{
 padding: 0 17px 0 40px;
}

.blog-list_info p{
 padding-bottom: 28px;
 line-height: 28px;
 color: #737373;
 font-size: 16px;
}

.blog-list_info .brn{
 height: 35px;
 font-size: 14px;
 padding-top: 8px 27px 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="section blog">
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="blog-list">
    <div class="blog-list_item">
     <div class="blog-list_img">
      <img src="img/blog-img.png" alt="">
      <div class="blog-list_header">
       <span class="blog-list_icon">
        <span class="icon-slideshow"></span>
       </span>
       <h6 class="blog-list_title">
        Awesome Blog Post Title Goes Here
       </h6>
      </div>
     </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="blog-list_footer">
     <div class="blog-list_date">
      <span>21 Feb ‘14 </span>
      <span>John Doe</span>
      <span>24 Comments</span>
     </div>
     <div class="blog-list_info">
      <p>
       Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit. Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt auctor a ornare odio. Sed non  mauris vitae erat consequat auctor eu in elit.
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Read On</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-list_item">
     <div class="blog-list_img">
      <img src="img/blog-img.png" alt="">
      <div class="blog-list_header">
       <span class="blog-list_icon">
        <span class="icon-slideshow"></span>
       </span>
       <h6 class="blog-list_title">
        Awesome Blog Post Title Goes Here
       </h6>
      </div>
     </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="blog-list_footer">
     <div class="blog-list_date">
      <span>21 Feb ‘14 </span>
      <span>John Doe</span>
      <span>24 Comments</span>
     </div>
     <div class="blog-list_info">
      <p>
       Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit. Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt auctor a ornare odio. Sed non  mauris vitae erat consequat auctor eu in elit.
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Read On</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-list_item">
     <div class="blog-list_img">
      <img src="img/blog-img.png" alt="">
      <div class="blog-list_header">
       <span class="blog-list_icon">
        <span class="icon-slideshow"></span>
       </span>
       <h6 class="blog-list_title">
        Awesome Blog Post Title Goes Here
       </h6>
      </div>
     </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="blog-list_footer">
     <div class="blog-list_date">
      <span>21 Feb ‘14 </span>
      <span>John Doe</span>
      <span>24 Comments</span>
     </div>
     <div class="blog-list_info">
      <p>
       Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit. Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt auctor a ornare odio. Sed non  mauris vitae erat consequat auctor eu in elit.
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Read On</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-list_item">
     <div class="blog-list_img">
      <img src="img/blog-img.png" alt="">
      <div class="blog-list_header">
       <span class="blog-list_icon">
        <span class="icon-slideshow"></span>
       </span>
       <h6 class="blog-list_title">
        Awesome Blog Post Title Goes Here
       </h6>
      </div>
     </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="blog-list_footer">
     <div class="blog-list_date">
      <span>21 Feb ‘14 </span>
      <span>John Doe</span>
      <span>24 Comments</span>
     </div>
     <div class="blog-list_info">
      <p>
       Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit. Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt auctor a ornare odio. Sed non  mauris vitae erat consequat auctor eu in elit.
      </p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning">Read On</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из кода мне видно, что для этих блоков ширина и не задана.

```
.blog-list_info{
padding: 0 17px 0 40px;
}

.blog-list_info p{
    padding-bottom: 28px;
    line-height: 28px;
    color: #737373;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```